# How can I use AsyncStorage to save my login credentials in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and can't seem to figure this out. I'm able to log into the API I need to connect to, however I need to figure out how to save the login credentials.

I'm currently using AsyncStorage for this but I'll probably move to `react-native-secure-key-store` soon instead. It's not allowing me to use this, when I try, it throws an error about how Null isn't an object. So, for now I'm just using AsyncStorage.

Here is the code I am currently using to import AsyncStorage:

```
import { AsyncStorage, Image, StyleSheet, View, Text, Platform } from "react-native";
```

Code in Login.ts that saves the login credentials:

```
console.log("logging user in...")
const username = this.state.username;
const password = this.state.password;
// save the item to AsyncStorage
AsyncStorage.setItem("username", JSON.stringify(username));
console.log(username);
```

Code in Secured.ts that gets the credentials:

```
// get item from AsyncStorage
const username = AsyncStorage.getItem("username") || 'none';
// set the state to include the username
this.state = {
  username: username,
};
console.log(this.state.username);
```

Here is what I'm getting from `console.log(this.state.username);` in Secured.ts:

```
_ {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

Why is it not returning the username I provided?

Thanks in advance, I hope I worded my question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `AsyncStorage` is migrated fro `react-native` to `react-native-community`.

You need to install it from there.

[Here](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) is the docs and guide for that.

Now to use it you need to make your `method` or `function` `async` and use `await` keyword to wait for the result.

see this,

to get data =>

```
getData=async()=>{ //async is needed to use await
   let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("yourKey")
}
```

the same way you can store data.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I'm trying to display the username stored in AsyncStorage, but when I try to do that, it's not working... I have `let username = await AsyncStorage.getItem("username");` as my code to get the username, and `return username;` to return the username but when I use `<Text style={styles.text}>{this.getData}</Text>` nothing shows up in the React Native app. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: see this is asynchronous task, thats why we have used await right. because it take some time to get data(just a fraction of second). so your function at TEXT will be executed and will return nothing because await is still pending. So what you can do is store your data in state. and instead calling function use state variable there.

Comment: can i use it to store user credential? I'm trying to implement authentication, is it a good practice to save the user credentials and every time the app is opened to log in again with the saved credentials?

Comment: As it sounds, it not a good idea to store creds anywhere apart from secured storages, would suggest you to use refresh token management for sessions. and still its requirement to store anyhow, encrypt them to add extra layer of security.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` is totally unencrypted so user login credentials are at risk so you can use the bellow package for storing data.

```
npm i react-native-encrypted-asyncstorage
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment friend

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

That's because of all the AsyncStorage methods returns a Promise, and you should wait for the response.

One way is to just put the `await` keyword

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem("username", JSON.stringify(username));

// ...

const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem("username") || 'none';
```

And you should be able to get the username.

If you don't know what Promises are, please read some docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Examples

Comment: `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function.`